# How to convert batch to exe programmatically

Tags: java, exe

I want to know how I can convert a .bat file to a .exe file programmatically in Java, I'mm trying to make a Batch IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Thank you Joe C for the warm welcome, I really appreciate it and I will check out the link in the comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code that I found online:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\executable.exe");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c c:\\batch_file.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

More information on this topic can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21452224).

Comment: Thank you Mine Rockers, I really appreciate you for being so kind to a new user on this site, why do you have -1 though?

Comment: Read the full post for more information.

Comment: Actually it does -Andrew Li you should have actually tried it, could you remove the -1?

Comment: @2OP4u All this does is run commands. If this answered the question, then edit your question to make it more clear of what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: I asked how this can be done programmatically, he showed me how. It's it what my question clearly wants? (Not trying to sound rude sorry)

Comment: @2OP4u Well, in the question you ask how to convert a batch file to an exe file, so how does this answer the question in the question?

Comment: I used the word programmatically, meaning I don't want the answers linking me to websites like BatchToExe or AdvanceBatchTToExe, but to instead show me the code necessary to do it in Java.

Comment: @2OP4u But this answer just executes a batch and exe file, it does no converting...

Comment: OHH I get what you mean now... yea you're right... but at least he shows me a link... and hes the only person who posted an answer.

Comment: I'm with @AndrewLi on this one. Closing question